# Fetch unique values from first columns and concat the values of other columns using spark dataframe

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with two columns
I need to fetch unique values from first columns and concat the values of other columns

for ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpSxG.png)

I wanted output as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pBY9.png)

how to achieve this using spark dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide these simple script in your question. It will be answered more easy.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    column1 sysname,
    column2 CHAR(1)
);

INSERT @Table (column1, column2)
VALUES ('D112', 'a'),
    ('D232', 'b'),
    ('D112', 'c'),
    ('D334', 'd'),
    ('D232', 'e'),
    ('D112', 'f');
```

AND THEN here is the answer:

```
SELECT t.column1, STRING_AGG(t.column2, ',')
FROM @Table AS t
GROUP BY t.column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupBy($"column1").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"column2")))
```